# Is it possible to delete the network peer database without deleting the chain data?

Tags: nodes, networking

The Substrate chain and Parachain data directory contains 3 sub-directories, `db`, `keystore`, and `network`.

A long time ago the `network` directory used to contain the database of peers, but now appears to be unused. However the peer database must exist *somewhere*.

1. Where is it now?
2. Can it be removed without having to delete all chain data from the `db` directory (i.e. using `purge-chain`) to force a node to rebuild it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We currently don't store the known peers. There is an [issue](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/4750) to bring this back. So, currently you only find the node key file in the `network` directory.